# When do students look for jobs?

Tags: dream-house-days

A number of my tenants are students. My very first tenant was originally a student, but he got employed after a while with no real active participation on my part as far as I know.

Students unfortunately pay very low rent. While I have nothing against jobless bums probably living off their parents' salaries and who just go shopping more often than not, I want to keep my monthly profit as high as possible, as soon as possible.

When do students look for jobs? Is this predetermined? Or is it all random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Kairosoft wiki page](http://kairosoft.wikia.com/wiki/Dream_House_Days), a person is a student for 3 years before he or she becomes an adult and looks for a job.